# How to pass a Class as method parameter?

Tags: java, class, introspection

I have the following class hierarchy :

Super Class and subclasses:

```
public class SuperClass(){

// attributes and accessors


public class Class1() extends SuperClass {

// attributes and accessors
}

public class Class2() extends SuperClass {

// attributes and accessors
}

public class Class3() extends SuperClass {

// attributes and accessors
}
```

I have also a method in other class to create the subclasses :

```
SuperClass createMySubclass(){

}
```

I wondering how i can pass in this method parameter the class i want to create and create his instance ? I don't know how to do it :

I would like to to do something like :

```
    SuperClass createMySubclass(Class myClass){

      SuperClass type = new myClass.getConstructor();

    }
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes -- Sorry, questions that ask for a one word answer aren't really good questions.

Comment: Also, there is no `getConstructor()` method on class objects. You can get a list of constructors, or you can find the exact one by providing a full signature.

Comment: Sure. When you call the method you'll pass in a real value and the method parameter will be resolved. Also, `getConstructor()` is unnecessary.

Comment: You can't use new in that way, and you shouldn't have parenthesis after the class names on the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

Given your scenario, as every class inhertis from SuperClass, you can have method with a SuperClass  as a parameter, and it could recieve any of its subclasses.

Example:

```
   SuperClass createMySubclass(SuperClass myClass){

      SuperClass type = myClass;

    }
```

and somewhere in your main, you should have something like this:

```
Class1 mySubClass = new Class1();
SuperClass mySuperClass = new SuperClass();
mySuperClass.createMySubClass(mySubClass);
```